# terraform.tfstate not working with workspace

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

i used tf code to deploy AWS infrastructure, the terraform.tfstate stored locally on my machine. I now want to centralised my code to github and also started using terraform workspace so that i can use the same tf code with separate state file stored in separate s3 buckets for each region/workspace.

when i am running my new code pointing it to the terraform.tfstate file from the old deployment then i am getting prompted for `Plan: 26 to add, 0 to change, 25 to destroy.` i am expecting terraform to not to show any `add` or `destroy` as there is no change to infrastructure other than use of bash script to create workspace and store/read the state file remotely.

i notice i get the same message `Plan: 26 to add, 0 to change, 25 to destroy.` even when i  copy the old `terraform.tfstate` to new code directory locally (not from remote s3). This is to troubleshoot if its anything to do with remote terraform.tfstate file. what could i be doing wrong here? wondering how can i have existing terraform state to work with workspace?

Comment: Is it this issue? https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/13799

Comment: thanks! i am already using the backend s3 block and also tried keeping the state file locally but no luck. I dont see the fix in that link?  `{
  backend "s3" {
   bucket = "testing-d-tf-state"
   key    = "aws-xyz/terraform.tfstate"
   region = "us-west-2"
  }
}`

Comment: there is no fix, it's still an open issue. I managed to resolve using `terraform state push terraform.tfstate.backup` as mentioned in the initial description

Comment: tried adding `aws-vault exec $2 -- terraform state push terraform.tfstate.backup` in my bash script but no luck.. still getting `add` and `destroy`